# LINQ Parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Give this xml structure:

```
    <store-fax-info>
      <store-info store-status="1" store-service-type="2">
        <store-guid>blah-blah-blah-blah</store-guid>
        <store-name>Avacados R Us</store-name>
        <phone>555-555-5555</phone>
        <fax>123-456-789</fax>
        <attention>Rockhead Rumble</attention>
      </store-info>
      <selected-clerk>
        <clerk-info guid="x">
          <clerk name="full-name" label="Clerk Name" value="" />
        </clerk-info>
        <item-info>
          <item-name="item-model" label="Item Model" value="Super Spuds" />
          <item-name="item-model-num" label="Model Number value="55555" />
          <item-name="family" label="Veggie Family" value="Tuber" />
          <item-name="serial-number" label="Serial Number" value="ABC123456A" />
          <item-name="date-checked" label="Last Date Checked" value="Mar 15 2012 11:00AM" />
          <item-name="item-weight" label="Weight" value="20lbs />
        <item-info>
      </selected-clerk>
    </store-fax-info>
```

I'm after the attributes in the item-info node, specifically the last value of each attribute. The kicker is, I only need 4 of the 6 attributes. I've been hammering on this all day. I take that xml and shove it in an XElement, let's call it info. When I write this:

```
    var query = from i in info.Elements("item-info")
                from j in i.Elements()
                select j;
```

At this point I can see all six of the item-name... lines. The purpose is I would like to get the values and put them into a class object. Roughly pseudocoded the desired outcome is....

```
    select new MyObject()
    {
        Product = query.SuperSpuds,
        Number = query.55555,
        SerialNumber = query.ABC123456A,
        CheckedDate = query.Mar 15 2012 11:00AM,
    }
```

I can't seem to massage the LINQ query to do what I need.

Comment: The xml is invalid... what are these supposed to be?? `<item-name="item-model" label="Item Model" value="Super Spuds" />` the element has no name, just a bunch of attributes!?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I should have mentioned. This is an xml snippet that gets passed around. Ultimately it ends up merging with other snippets. I'm just hijacking the snippet to get what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your xml is not well-formed.

Things like

`<item-name="item-model" label="Item Model" value="Super Spuds" />`

are not allowed. If you want to store text inside element use this:

`<item-name label="Item Model" value="Super Spuds">item-model</item-name>`

However if you change XML to valid one the following code may help you:

```
var xElements = xElement.Descendants("item-name").Attributes("value").ToList();

var o = new MyObject()
            {
                Product = xElements[0].Value,
                Number = xElements[1].Value,
                SerialNumber = xElements[2].Value,
                CheckedDate = xElements[3].Value
            };
```

Comment: This got me on my way, thanks a ton the_joric. I addressed the xml issue above. Tested the code and it gives me what I need.